# Junit parameterized testing ,a different thought

Tags: java, selenium, junit

Here,
I have a custom independent component which accept input as a jar file and identify the `junit` test classes from it and execute them using the code given below.

```
Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(cls);//cls is Class<?>instance.
```

Next thing I required is a provision to inject parameters (Assuming that input jar includes  selenium based test it requires different browsers as parameters )
So I required to inject different browser as parameters to the junit from my independent component. 
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a different call to JUnitCore and implement your own custom computer. The custom computer can generate a parameterized runner if your test class is annotated with your own annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CustomParameterized {}
```

Like so:

```
@CustomParameterized
public class Example {

  private String arg;

  public Example(String arg){
    this.arg = arg;
  }

  @org.junit.Test
  public void test(){
    assertEquals("a",arg);
  }

}
```

The JUnitCore call would become:

```
String[] args = new String[]{"a","b"}
Request request = Request.classes(new CustomComputer(args), Example.class);
Result result = new JUnitCore().run(request);
```

The custom computer looks like:

```
  public class CustomComputer extends Computer {

  private final List<Object> args;

  public CustomComputer(String[] args) {
      this.args = Arrays.<Object>asList(args);
  }

  @Override
  protected Runner getRunner(RunnerBuilder builder, final Class<?> testClass) throws Throwable {
      if (testClass.isAnnotationPresent(Test.CustomParameterized.class)) {
          final BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParametersFactory factory = new BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParametersFactory();
          return new CustomParameterizedRunner(testClass, factory);
      }
      return builder.runnerForClass(testClass);
  }

  private class CustomParameterizedRunner extends Suite {
      private final Class<?> testClass;
      private final BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParametersFactory factory;

      public CustomParameterizedRunner(Class<?> testClass, BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParametersFactory factory) throws InitializationError {
          super(testClass, Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
          this.testClass = testClass;
          this.factory = factory;
      }

      @Override
      protected List<Runner> getChildren() {
          List<Runner> runners = new ArrayList<>();
          for (Object arg : args) {
              runners.add(runnerFor(arg, testClass, factory));
          }
          return runners;
      }
  }


  private static Runner runnerFor(Object arg, Class<?> testClass, BlockJUnit4ClassRunnerWithParametersFactory factory) {
      ArrayList<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<>(1);
      parameters.add(arg);
      String name = testClass.getSimpleName() + "[" + arg + "]";
      TestWithParameters test = new TestWithParameters(name, new TestClass(testClass), parameters);
      try {
        return factory.createRunnerForTestWithParameters(test);
      } catch (InitializationError initializationError) {
        throw new RuntimeException(initializationError);
      }
  }
}
```